# What is the use of (으)로 here?

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean, korean-to-english, connective-suffix

'오늘 그사람을 만나면 낯선 사람으로 대할 거예요' The only confusion I have here is 으로 which has the meaning of with, by or towards(a place).This sentence means 'If I meet that person today I am going to treat him like a stranger',so shouldn't it be 처럼 instead of 으로 which doesn't make sense?

Comment: 으로 can also mean '으로서'. The original sentence can be translated as: "If I meet that person today, I'll treat him as a stranger." If you use 처럼, it would be "I'll treat him like a stranger." Subtle difference, but doesn't really matter in spoken language.

Answer (score -1):

오늘 그 사람을 만나면 낯선 사람을 대할거에요.
I am pretty sure you need a space between 그 and 사람
Also, it is 대할거'에'요 not 대할거'예'요

Back to your question,

낯선 사람으로 대할거에요

or

낯선 사람인 것 처럼 대할거에요

they both make sense. I would not say both can be used interchangably because it depends on the context

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this answer is both vague and misleading. 거예요 is correct, and there should be no space between 것 and 처럼.